# How to trigger new deployment in openshift when we change openshift config maps

Tags: openshift

i have implemented following things in openshift

created Config Map In openshift for environmental configurations

reading those config maps as environmental variables in openshift.

I have a requirement like whenever i change values in the config maps new POD 
   needs to be created.

Please suggest me how i can achieve this?

Comment: You use the term build, but config maps aren't used in builds. Do you mean a deployment?

Comment: yes, it is for deployments, thanks for pointing out , corrected the question

Comment: Have you looked at the ``oc rollout latest`` command? You can also trigger a new deployment from the deployment details in the web console. There is no way to have a new deployment triggered automatically when a config map is updated, so you need to use one of those methods. Other option is not to use environment variables, mount the config map as a file and have application detect when file for config map changes on update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i thought we can create some sort of trigger like whenever config map changes we can create new POD, you said that not possible, i have old application which won't support the reading of file mounted file when it changes. i will look for the alternatives, thanks.

Comment: A new deployment would only be triggered when updating environment variables, if the environment variables are part of the deployment config itself, rather than being in separate config map or secret.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no out of the box solution yet.
However i solved this issue by generating a hash of my config map "CONFIG_HASH".

This hash is then mounted in the container as an environment variable:

```
      env:
      - name: CONFIG_HASH
        value: ${CONFIG_HASH}
```

Consequently, each time the config changes, a deployment is triggered (because the environment has changed).

You will however likely have to use a pipeline (Jenkins, GitlabCI,...) to do this...

Comment: But in this case you should manually change it everytime

Answer (score 0):

I trigger redeploy when any value changes in `values.yaml` by doing this:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ .Values | toJson | sha256sum }}
```